# KVM live migration for non shared lvm storage

Tags: kvm-virtualization, storage, virsh, live-migration

I am trying to live migrate my KVM based VM from one host to another for **non shared storage** using virsh migrate. I have set both the hostnames at **/etc/hosts** on each of the host. Also I have set passwordless SSH between the hosts. Still i am not able to live migrate my VM.

Steps I followed:

1. Created a vm on host1 with a lv
2. Created a dummy lv on host2
3. symlink the host2 lv with host1 vm disk
4. executed command: `virsh migrate --live --persistent --verbose --copy-storage-all --dname test_1 --desturi qemu+ssh://root@host2/system v1007`

I get error:

> error: internal error: cannot precreate storage for disk type 'block'

Can anyone help to sort this issue? Is anything that I might be missing out?
Thank you

Comment: What versions of everything are you using?

Comment: @MichaelHampton libvirtd (libvirt) 4.5.0  storage is lvm based 
What else do you require can you please specify.

Comment: You forgot the Linux distribution too?

Comment: @MichaelHampton          i am using centos 7.0

Comment: Why isn't your system up to date? There is a known bug that fixes this problem but that was years ago, and CentOS 7.0 did not have the fix. You should be updating your system on a regular basis.

Comment: Here is a bug description - https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=8281

Comment: @MichaelHampton  thank you.  i updated 
Name        : qemu-kvm
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 10
Version     : 1.5.3
Release     : 173.el7_8.3
Size        : 1.9 M
Repo        : updates/7/x86_64
but still it did not help

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a known bug in early versions of qemu.

I don't think this bug was ever fixed in the ancient version of qemu-kvm shipped with base CentoS 7.

However, AFAIK it is fixed in the CentOS Virt SIG's release of qemu-kvm-ev, which is much newer, and tracks the source code for the enterprise [Red Hat Virtualization](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/virtualization/enterprise-virtualization) product. I use this on some CentOS 7 hypervisors and live migration works well.

You can update to the Virt SIG builds by simply enabling their repo and then updating your system:

```
yum install centos-release-qemu-ev
yum distro-sync
```

After this update you should reboot the computer to ensure that everything is started with the new packages.